# Alternative to solve the DeadLock in java

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

I am reading [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) from Oracle.

And there is an example of the [DeadLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

Core code:

```
    public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s" + "  has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }

    public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s" + " has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
```

And then when the tutorial goes to the [LockObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html), it provide a solution to handle the deadlock by the [Lock Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).

Now I wonder if there is an alternative method to avoid the deadlock without using the `Lock` Object?

Comment: Implement the `Lock` behavior.

Comment: Is that the only choice?

Comment: You need a mechanism for time out trying to acquire a monitor. I think `Lock` implementations use some `sun.misc.Unsafe` logic.

Answer (score 3):

One way of avoiding a deadlock is breaking the symmetry by imposing an order in which the two locks are acquired. For example you may say that when initiating a bow the thread should always put a lock on the friend whose name comes first in alphabetic order, so that any thread doing a bow must acquire the lock on Alphonse first and then the lock on Gaston, never in reverse:

```
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        Friend lock = (this.name.compareTo(bower.name)<0)? this : bower);
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
    }
    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        Friend lock = (this.name.compareTo(bower.name)>0)? this : bower);
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
```

A lock-free option is using an atomic variable to signal if a bow is already in progress, and wait if there is one:

```
    private static AtomicBoolean bowing = new AtomicBoolean();
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        while (!bowing.compareAndSet(false, true)) Thread.yield();

        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);

        bowing.set(false);
    }
```

Yet another way of avoiding deadlock is using a single lock instead of two; two threads competing for a single lock cannot deadlock.

```
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
    }

    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's wonderful! I have never thought the `synchronized` can be used like this. BTW, could you recommend some tutorial about `thread,concurrency` in java? Since the tutorial I mentioned in the post is rather high level, I need some further detailed guide. :)